# how do I show an image full screen

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I show a UIImageview fullscreen (programmatically) so that it takes the whole view in Objective-C? I tried doing:

```
   [self.centerImage setFrame: CGRectMake(self.centerImage.frame.origin.x, self.centerImage.frame.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
```

but the origin.x just does not give me a full screen representation

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "whole view" will vary in size depending what device you're on. So the first step is to use auto layout and pin the four sides of the image view to the four sides of its superview. Now it exactly covers the "whole view". You will then have to play with the content mode, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the image to full screen then assign the frame of your view to your image view like this

```
self.centerImage.frame = self.view.frame
```